# Intersection of an ideal and a subring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Is there a Grobner basis method that can compute the intersection of an ideal $I$ of a polynomial ring $R$ and its subring $R^\prime$? For example, I have an ideal $I=(x+y+z^2,1+xyz+yz+xz)$ of $\mathbb{F}_2[x,y,z]$ and want to find its intersection with the subring $\mathbb{F}_2[x^2,y^2,z^2]$

Comment: You can apply elimination theory (see e.g. §15.10.4 of Eisenbud) to the ideal $$(x+y+z^2,1+xyz+yz+xz,x^2-a,y^2-b,z^2-c) \subseteq \mathbf F_2[a,b,c,x,y,z].$$ I think in general you're supposed to reduce to such a situation (although I may be mistaken ― I am far from an expert). I guess the point is that if $R'$ is not a polynomial ring, we want to work with a presentation of $R'$ anyway.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324762/a-presentation-for-a-subalgebra#comment810666_324762